# How can I pass data to dompdf from controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, dompdf

this is my controller:

```
function dompdf(){
            $this->load->view('contracts/equipment_pdf');
            $html = $this->output->get_output();
            $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');
            $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
            $this->dompdf->render();
            $this->dompdf->stream("test.pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
    }
```

Q: How can i add data there? like $data['name'] = "name";

Q2: How can i put the data in my pdf generator? how will i call it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `view()` method accepts three parameters. You can pass your data as the second parameter. By setting the third parameter to true, you are able to load the view as a string to pass to your pdf class.

```
    function dompdf(){
       $data['name'] = "name";
       $html = $this->load->view('contracts/equipment_pdf', $data, true);
       $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');
       $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
       $this->dompdf->render();
       $this->dompdf->stream("test.pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
   }
```

For the above example, you can access the data in your view using:

```
<?php echo $name; ?>
```