# how do i solve dompdf error?

Tags: codeigniter, dompdf

I am using dopdf for my reports and on one of the reports it gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Inline_Frame_Decorator::normalise() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sraerca\system\helpers\dompdf\include\table_frame_decorator.cls.php
>   on line 252

But works fine with other reports.

Comment: Can you edit your question with code where can be seen how do you use it?

Comment: As I've mentioned [elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829828/convert-html-file-to-pdf-using-dompdf): dompdf is somewhat flexible in dealing with structural problems, but not *that* much. Likely it's having a problem handling your code due to a structural problem with your HTML. Try running the HTML through a [validator](http://validator.w3.org) and addressing any major issues found. If that doesn't work update your question with a sample of the HTML document.

Comment: Try this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087338/how-can-i-pass-data-to-dompdf-from-controller